# How to make VBA do the same actions while changing criteria until it hits an empty cell?

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am trying to create a simple VBA macro that would help me with some work that I am currently doing manually.

The idea is that there is a given list, of that list column "A" will contain data that I will need to filter on on another sheet, copy the result to another sheet and move on with the next cell below.

```
Sheets("Sheet4").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$R$25239").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A3").Value
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet5").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "+"
```

I need VBA to repeat this step until the it hits the bottom of the list, however I also need the range to change to the cell one below at the Filter criteria.

I would really appreciate some help as I am a beginner.

Comment: You use Active and Select. Do not!

Comment: Look around at "VBA For loops" which should pretty quickly show you the way to do this.  Basically, declare a range (`set myRng = Range("A1:A10")` then a `For` loop: `For each cel in myRng // cel.value = "123" (do whatever) // next cel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to understand what you were wanting to do but this will copy any thing from sheet one A1 to A100 that contains "_" which you can change to match your filter, if you can clear this up what your filtering by ill amend. it then puts it in sheet2 and puts a "+" between each entry

```
Sub test()
Dim myArray(1 To 1000) As Variant, cell As Range, myRng As Range, myRng2 As Range, cell2 As Range, Pos As Long, criteria As Variant


Set myRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A1000") 'You can change this to be your correct source sheet, and range

Set myRng2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A1000") 'You can change this to be your correct destination sheet, and range

criteria = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Value 'Your search criteria lives here


Pos = 1

    For Each cell In myRng
        If cell.Value <> "" And InStr(cell.Value, criteria) > 0 Then 'you can change the criteria to anything you want.
             myArray(Pos) = cell.Value
             Pos = Pos + 1
        End If
    Next cell

Pos = 1

    For Each cell2 In myRng2
        If cell2.Value = "" Then
            cell2.Value = myArray(Pos)

            If cell2.Value <> "" Then
               cell2.Offset(1, 0).Value = "+"
            End If

            Pos = Pos + 1
        End If
    Next cell2


Set myRng = Nothing
Set myRng2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Almost, let's say on Sheet1 there is my list that I need to go through every day and in column A there is information that I need to find out some details about it so on Sheet2 that will be my filter criteria. After found all the information I want the whole table to be selected and copied to another sheet then go to the very bottom of it and put a "+" between each entry for formatting. The problem is that the list could be as short as 20 lines or as long as 200 and if I copy blank data to sheet3 (because that's what I've filtered on) it will screw it.

Comment: edited the code so that it will look for the criteria stored in Cell A1 on sheet 3 ignore any blank cells and will copy any data that matches the criteria and put it into sheet2 with a "+" between each entry

Answer (score 0):

as and example

```
dim myRng as range, cell as range

set myRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("Your Range here" eg "A1:A20")


For each cell in myRng
      if "//your condition" eg cell.value = "1" Then
         "What you want to do with it here"
               "you can also nest another for each loop here to copy to your destination"
      End If
Next Cell
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete code, as I mentioned in the above comment, it doesn't really make sense to me so I have to do some google searches to understand it and make it work :).

Comment: myRng is the range you want to look ie the one you "set", what the above code is saying is look for each cell in the range starting in this case at A1 check if the value of it meets your condition . The next line is what you want to do with it if it does match the condition. It will now look at the next cell and check that and so on. it will keep going until it gets to the last cell you declared in this case A20.

Answer (score 0):

Your recorded code  can be replaced with

```
 Dim source as range
 Set source = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("$A$1:$R$25239")
 dim crit as range
 set crit = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A3")
 Dim dest as range

 source.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= crit.Value
 set dest = sheets("Sheet5").range("a1").end(xldown).offset(1,0)
 Sheets("Sheet4").range("a1").currentregion.copy dest
 dest.offset(1,0) = "+"
```

Now add a loop to achieve what you want

Comment: Thanks. The code was originally recorded but it didn't do the work so I have manually edited it so it does the job. It looks like I have a lot to learn though because your code is much easier, it just doesn't make sense to me :).